# php.ini include_path - failed to open stream errors

Tags: wamp, php, include-path, require-once

I am on a four month coop with a web development firm, and am currently trying to implement some new functionality to their project management tool.  I have the source and am trying to get it set up locally for testing purposes.
I am using windows 7 and wamp.

I have spent the entire day today failing with this, have found dozens of similar (potentially identical) questions on stack overflow which have not assisted me, and read the documentation on the php.ini that seemed related.

The code - not mine - uses a constant ROOT value which I have set to work with my structure.
define('ROOT', '/ac_test/public_html/||||'); (|||| is just the software they use).

When I load up the index.php file it attempts to include a file:
require_once ROOT . '/defaults.php';

At this point it fails and gives me this error: 
Warning: require_once(/ac_test/public_html/****/defaults.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\ac_test\public_html\config\defaults.php on line 14

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/ac_test/public_html/||||/defaults.php' (include_path='*PATH ATTEMPTS BELOW') in C:\wamp\www\ac_test\public_html\config\defaults.php on line 14

I have altered the include_path in my php.ini file to be just about everything.  I've attempted relative paths (.;..;../../../.. etc), I have attempted direct paths (c:/wamp/www for example) and probably 20+ other nonsensical possibilities.  I have used get_include_path() to output the path which ends up being identical to where the file is, and I have used the full, direct path without using ROOT, and it works, but I can't use that.  There are hundreds of coded references in the code that require me to use the ROOT constant and for the include_path to function.

I realize this question has been asked before, many many times.  I've likely read every post on stack overflow today regarding it.  They're all similar.  So is mine, but I'm out of ideas.  I should also mention that I began web development and php only 2 months ago with this coop.  I have some very big holes in my knowledge, and so I may have overlooked something very simple.

Comment: what happens if you echo this value: $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

Comment: I would try setting `ROOT` to the absolute file path of your project. `C:\wamp\www\ac_test\public_html` in your case